# Вывести все переменные из другого файла, а не только одну

Tags: php, классы, функции

Есть файл с классом и функцией Profile.php:

```
<?php class News {
    public static function getNewsList() {
        $api = "123123123";
        return $api;
        $logmein = "xyz";

//Функция большая, это её начало.
```

Есть файл который  включает в себя код выше:

```
<?php
include_once ROOT. '/models/Profile.php';    
class ProfileController {

    public function actionIndex()
    {


        $api = News::getNewsList();
        echo $api; // Выводит на экран APi

        //Когда я ещё раз вызываю что-то:
        $logmein = News::getNewsList();
        echo $logmein //Notice: Constant DB already defined in 

        return true;
    }
```

Функция подключается, даже на экран выводится api, но как мне вывести другие переменные из этого файла ? Если перевызывать функцию, ты вылетает много ошибок, мол то что я вызываю уже используется. Как грамотно можно вывести остальные переменные ?

Comment: покажите как вы повторно вызываете, и какая ошибка возникает

Comment: @Bookin Внёс правку

Comment: 1 - return завершает выполнение функции. `getNewsList` вернет только `$api`.  Можно вернуть массив: `return array("api" => $api, "logmein" => $logmein);`, а в `actionIndex` получать доступ к значениям по индексам.  2 - `Constant DB already defined in` что еще за DB? Вероятно повторный вызов метода `getNewsList` приводит к переопределению константы.

Comment: @UserName Сделал return array(...) Но когда попытался вывести через var_dump($user_data['logmein']);, мне пишет, что переменная не определена и значение массива - null

Comment: Вероятно операция в результате которой устанавливается значение отрабатывает неправильно, поэтому `logmein` установлено в null. Нужно локализовать проблему, т.е проверить результаты вызовов функций, которые значения устанавливают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем варианте в файле profile.php функция getNewsList() всегда будет возвращать $api.

Чтобы возвращать разные значения, вам нужно создать отдельные функции для каждого значения и вызывать их из `actionIndex()`, например:

```
public static function getNewsListApi() {
    $api = "123123123";
    return $api;
}
public static function getNewsListLogMeIn() {
    $logmein = "xyz";
    return $logmein;
}
```

Вызов функций:

```
 $api = News::getNewsList();
 $logmein = News::getNewsList();
```

Либо, второй вариант, вернуть значения массивом:

```
public static function getNewsList() {
    $api = "123123123";
    $logmein = "xyz";

    $arr = array(
        "api" => $api,
        "logmein" => $logmein
    );
    return $arr;
}
```

И обрабатывать следующим образом:

```
 $data = News::getNewsList();
 $api = $data['api'];
 $logmein = $data['logmein'];
```

Comment: А можно ли просто вызвать News::getNewsList(); не присваивая ей ничего ? Я так сделал и всё работает. Я сделал плохо ? Или так можно ?

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю логику программы дальнейшую, не видя остального кода, поэтому затрудняюсь ответить.

Comment: Если вам не нужно от функции ничего получать и вся логика выгоняется в ней, то можно просто вызвать News::getNewsList(); без присваивания. Если я правильно понял про какое присваивание вы спрашиваете)